# How to create a site like AngelList?

Tags: content-management-system, clone

I want to create a site like AngelList for a different target, but i can't code a site like that from scratch. Are there scripts or CMS for creating a site like AngelList?

Answer (score -1):

It's unlikely that you'll find a CMS for that exact purpose without at least some knowledge of web development technologies. You could try [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) or [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) as a starting point, but be prepared for some work.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Do you know some plugins/themes for those CMS to make them similar to AL? I've some knowledge of Web Development so i can work with CMS.